# How to shift the register while using SIPO shift register?

Tags: circuit-design, simulation, shift-register, homework, multisim

I have used this SIPO shift register and I've displayed the pattern that I wanted which is 01011000 but I don't know how to shift it now? How can I make the LEDs move? 
I've been told to insert a load to make it shift, but I have no clue how to make a load with this
[image]

Comment: How did you set the initial pattern to be 01011000?

Comment: As already answered in your previous questions, you will need to load the pattern in to the shift register, what you have down cannot be shifted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LED bar pattern shift (right to left) using 555 timer resistors and LEDs and SIPO shift register](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/493963/led-bar-pattern-shift-right-to-left-using-555-timer-resistors-and-leds-and-sip)

Comment: it doesn't really answer it because i tried but i didn't have the results i want, how can i load?

Comment: and i used the nand gate and NOT gate to make it display

Comment: We can't see in this diagram which shift register you are using. Nevertheless, you need some source of serial bits to load the shift register. With every clock the bit from the serial input is taken and stuffed into the buffer. If you want to cycle it, you will need two phases, first with the source of your data connected to the input, second with the serial output connected to the input. This could be done with XOR-gates. Investigate!

Answer (score 0):

Based on this and your [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/493963/led-bar-pattern-shift-right-to-left-using-555-timer-resistors-and-leds-and-sip), it doesn't appear that you understand what a shift register is. In this context, people say "load" to mean put the data into the register. PISO (Parallel in - serial out) means that all bits are loaded at once, but are clocked out one at a time. Conversely, SIPO (serial in - parallel out) means that one bit is shifted in at a time, and all are available at the output after the load completes.

In your circuit, you are not shifting in any data. You are statically setting the outputs based on the NAND and NOT gates. The 555 timer as a clock is pointless (beyond shifting in your initial pattern). As it is, you **cannot** shift the output bits in any way. It is possible to do some sort of shenanigans with additional Parallel-in-serial-out registers and other logic gates, but that would be ridiculous.

The data-in line of your shift register needs to be coming from something that can dynamically set the logic level, not a constant logic level. It also needs to be timed to correlate with the output pulse frequency of your 555 timer based clock.